# Is 'metis' more or less offensive in use than 'halfcaste'?

Tags: meaning, offensive-language

Both 'mé-tis' and 'halfcaste' (also 'half-caste') mean, generally, 'of mixed blood'. Is one more or less offensive in contemporary use than the other?

Comment: Do you have any particular context in mind?

Comment: What about biracial?  In the US, it's probably the least offensive term.

Comment: Poly or Multi Ethnic is a good substitute that doesn't make assumptions about the subjects' background. Bi-racial is a bit limiting in that it can only refer to (2) races. If someone of half Asian heritage has a child with a Louisiana creole person you're looking at three "races", minimum. Additionally, the concept of "race" is outmoded, and may seem offensive in and of itself. Ethnicity is currently the accepted term, since the implication is not that the person is a "different kind" of human, but merely a different phenotype of humanity.

Comment: So short answer, YES. typically Half Castes and mestizos were treated as an inferior and laborer class. Similar anguage also applies to a racial caste system present in the American South during Slavery and based on the fraction of 'negro' blood a person had. Terms like octaroon, quadroon and "high yella' (yellow)" were it's legacy and are EXTREMELY offensive.

Comment: I would avoid them, regardless of context.  I think Josh's answer that includes "mixed heritage" is a good answer.

Comment: When I worked for the US census many years ago, I was told not to ask the person I was interviewing about their racial background but to point to a list and ask them "which one of these do you feel best applies to you?"  The list did not include "half-caste" or "metis."

Comment: Why are you asking this question? This might help people focus better, and give better answers. Would you use *half-caste* only in writing, in speech or indifferently between the two? Please add context to your question, otherwise I could tell you what my personal experience is since living in Italy, or when I was a child in the UK, when I lived in Ireland, Mexico, Australia  etc. etc.

Comment: Are you concerned with either BrEng and AmEng or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I'm not highly familiar with the situation, I associate the word *Metis/métis/metis* mainly with Canada. There is a Wikipedia article about the [Métis ethnic group in Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9tis_people_(Canada)) (I think they might have the pronunciation wrong, though: from what I remember the "s" is pronounced in French [Sources: [1](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/m%C3%A9tis),[2](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/m%C3%A9tis),[3](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1901/how-is-m%C3%A9tis-pronounced)] so leaving it off in English is probably a [hyperforeignism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperforeignism#French_words)). In that context, there are people who use the term for self-identification, so I would think it is considered less offensive than *half-caste*, which is described in the answers to this question ([*Is the term “halfcast” racist?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58354/is-the-term-halfcast-racist)) as "often offensive" or "derogatory." Of course, different people often take offense at different things; to know if either of these words are offensive to a specific person, you'd have to ask.

Comment: This turns out not to be a matter of opinion at all, for the reason you suggest (among others): 'Métis' is used today as self-identification; historically, it was used with something of a derogatory flavor by some people sometimes. See *Many Tender Ties*, etc. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is difficult to classify those terms with respect of how offensive they may or may not sound. The following ***[extract](http://www.mixedindifferentshades.net/articles/whats-in-a-name.php)*** may help with the meaning and usage of a number of different words that refer to the wide variety of existing mixed heritage:

> - Many languages have evolved names for mixed heritage people in their societies, some words being borrowed from other cultures and languages. Some of the terms have derogatory meaning in one part of the world and are entirely acceptable and proudly borne in other parts of the world.
> - Below is a table of terms used to describe some of mixed heritage people. ***It is interesting to note that some of the terms refer to actual ethnic groups where the offspring of two members of the same group are still regarded as mixed heritage.***
> - Multi-Racial Multi-Ethnic Mixed Heritage Mixed Race Bi-Racial Dual Heritag:,
>
>   - *Politically correct terms being used to describe people of two or multiple race or heritage.*
> - Creole:
>
>   - *Used in many different ways and not always necessarily but usually referring to ethnic groups of people of mixed heritage*
> - Half-caste, Half-cast:
>
>   - *A term used to describe people of mixed race or ethnicity and now regarded as a derogatory term in most parts of the world. The term originates from the Indian caste system, where a person of 'lesser' or half-caste would be deemed to be of a 'lower class'. The word caste may come from the Portuguese casta meaning race.*
> - Mestizo:
>
>   - *(Spanish casta/caste) Persons with one European parent and one Indian parent*.

(www.mixedindifferentshades)