# Do -ist words (e.g. racist) have superlative or comparative forms?

Tags: adjectives, comparatives, superlative-degree

Do -ist words (e.g. racist, sexist, etc.) have superlative or comparative forms?

Comment: “That’s the sexistest stuff I’ve seen all day” is surprisingly difficult to pronounce. Thank heavens _sexist_ doesn’t decline desinentially!

Comment: I searched on my disk for the string "ister" ... I found files in Turkish, and files containing the word "register".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some *-ist* words are used as adjectives, as I describe in my answer to "[*Adjectival Usage of Racist*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/337868/77227)".

The *-ist* words that are used as adjectives, such as *racist* and *sexist,* form periphrastic superlatives and comparatives using *most* and *more.* This is in accordance with the [general rule that restricts the inflectional superlative and comparative suffixes *-est* and *-er* to monosyllabic bases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/more-clear-vs-clearer-when-to-use-more-instead-of-er?noredirect=1&lq=1). (That rule is a simplification: *-est* and *-er* can actually be used on some bases of more than one syllable, and sometimes *most* and *more* can be used with monosyllables. But it's difficult to give a complete description of the distribution of *-est* and *-er* vs. *most* and *more,* and there is some variability in usage between speakers.)

So "most racist" and "more racist" exist, but *"racistest" and *"racister" don't exist.